# How to bind NSObject<EAAccessoryDelegate, NSStreamDelegate> in Monotouch?

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to bind a library and I have the following definitions on the .h files

```
@interface FbFAccessoryController : NSObject <EAAccessoryDelegate, NSStreamDelegate> {

    id <FbFmobileOneDelegate> _delegate;

    BOOL    ScannerStarted;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FbFmobileOneDelegate> delegate;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) BOOL Version1b;

- (BOOL)mobileOneConnected;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber *VoltIndex;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) BOOL ScannerStarted;

- (void)startScanner;

- (void)stopScanner;

- (void)checkBattery;

@end
```

For the Delegate

```
@class FbFAccessoryController;

@protocol FbFmobileOneDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void) mobileOneAccessoryController:(FbFAccessoryController *)mobileOne didChangeConnectionStatus:(BOOL)connected;

- (void) mobileOneAccessoryController:(FbFAccessoryController *)mobileOne didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;

@optional

- (void) mobileOneAccessoryController:(FbFAccessoryController *)mobileOne didReceiveError:(NSError *)error;

- (void) mobileOneAccessoryController:(FbFAccessoryController *)mobileOne didReceiveScannerStartStop:(BOOL)started;

- (void) mobileOneAccessoryController:(FbFAccessoryController *)mobileOne didReceiveDataSpin:(BOOL)started;

@end
```

I use ObjectiveSharpie to generate the bind but I when I try to compile I am getting the following error:

Type `MonoTouch.ExternalAccessory.EAAccessoryDelegate' in interface list is not an interface
Type`MonoTouch.Foundation.NSStreamDelegate' in interface list is not an interface

And the code generated by objectivesharpie is:

```
public partial interface FbFAccessoryController : EAAccessoryDelegate, NSStreamDelegate {


        [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
        FbFmobileOneDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

        [Static, Export ("sharedController")]
        FbFAccessoryController SharedController { get; }

        [Export ("Version1b")]
        bool Version1b { get; }

        [Export ("mobileOneConnected")]
        bool MobileOneConnected { get; }

        [Export ("VoltIndex")]
        NSNumber VoltIndex { get; }

        [Export ("ScannerStarted")]
        bool ScannerStarted { get; }

        [Export ("startScanner")]
        void StartScanner ();

        [Export ("stopScanner")]
        void StopScanner ();

        [Export ("checkBattery")]
        void CheckBattery ();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocols should be decorated with the `[Model]` attribute, so you can implement them as if they were interfaces.

So, without using ObjectiveSharpie, it should look like this:

```cs
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface FbFAccessoryController : EAAccessoryDelegate, NSStreamDelegate {

    [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
    FbFmobileOneDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    // ... //
}
```

Provided that the Delegates are defined like this:

```cs
[Model] //Look, no BaseType
interface EAAccessoryDelegate {
    // [Export] what you need here
}

[Model]
interface NSStreamDelegate {
    // [Export] what you need here
}
```